# How to fix long run times replacing values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with approx. 45,000 rows.  Currently I am looping through a column and targeting any cells with a value of 0.  Those row numbers get stored in an array.  I am then looping through that array, and changing another cell based on the array value.  I have 5000 rows with values that need to be reassigned, and it is taking over an hour to run that segment of the code (saving the row numbers to the array only takes a few seconds).  Any ideas on how to get the code to run faster?  Here is the code:

```
'Initialize array
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim x As Long

'Looks for the last row on the "Dates" sheet
Dim lastRow As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dates")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

Dim i As Integer
i = 2

Dim uCounter As Integer
'Loop through all the dates on the "Dates" sheet
While i <= lastRow
    'Each date has a counter next to it
    uCounter = Worksheets("Dates").Range("B" & i).Value
    Dim uDate As String
    'Store the date as a string
    uDate = Worksheets("Dates").Range("C" & i).Value
    Dim startRow As Long, endRow As Long
    'Finds the first and last instance of the date on the CERF Data page (45,000 rows)
    With Sheets("CERF Data")
        startRow = .Range("AN:AN").Find(what:=uDate, after:=.Range("AN1"), LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        endRow = .Range("AN:AN").Find(what:=uDate, after:=.Range("AN1"), LookIn:=xlValues, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End With

    Dim j As Long
    For j = startRow To endRow
        'If the cell in column BB is 0, and the counter is above 0 save row number to array, j being the variable representing row number
        If Sheets("CERF Data").Range("BB" & j).Value = 0 And uCounter > 0 Then
            'save row number to array
            ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
            myArray(x) = j
            x = x + 1
            'decrement counter by 1
            uCounter = uCounter - 1
        End If
        If uCounter = 0 Then Exit For
    Next j
i = i + 1
Wend

Dim y As Long
'Loop through the array and assign a value of 2 to all the rows in the array for column AS
For y = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    Sheets("CERF Data").Range("AS" & myArray(y)).Value = 2
Next y
```

Thanks!

Comment: We cannot help you without your code.

Comment: Without the code... Why don't you just get the whole sheet on the array and check your criteria, if match you can directly change whatever you need on the array and paste it back to the sheet. That would be barely seconds.

Comment: Posted the code.  Not a bad idea, I will give that a try.

Comment: @Djaenike Actually I would do the same as Damian but make sure you read the used range (containing data) only and not the whole sheet. Otherwise you read a lot of empty cells.

Comment: @Damian your solution worked!  Thanks

Comment: Some useful info on [creating arrays from a sheet range](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: @Djaenike if it worked, don't forget to mark it as answered so others can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more info this is what I can get you:

Just 1 loop through all the rows, once, checking both if the value on column BB = 0 and the date is within your range of dates:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim arr, i As Long, DictDates As Scripting.Dictionary

    arr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CERF Data").UsedRange.Value
    Set DictDates = New Scripting.Dictionary 'You need the Microsoft Scripting Runtime Reference for this to work

    'Create a dictionary with all the dates you must check
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dates")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If Not DictDates.Exists(CDate(.Cells(i, 3))) Then DictDates.Add CDate(.Cells(i, 3)), 1
        Next i
    End With

    'Only one loop through the whole array
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 54) = 0 And DictDates.Exists(CDate(arr(i, 40))) Then  'check your 2 criterias, date and value = 0
            arr(i, 45) = 2 'input the value 2 on the column "AS"
        End If
    Next i


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CERF Data").UsedRange.Value = arr

End Sub
```